# Regularity results for non uniform elliptic equation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-pde, regularity

I have seen some regularity result for ellptic PDE but all of them consist of uniform elliptic one. For instance,
$$\nabla \cdot (\gamma(x) \nabla u)=F \text{ in } \Omega\qquad u=\phi \text{ on }\partial \Omega$$
with $0<\lambda\le \gamma(x)\le \Lambda<\infty$.
Regularity result I am interested are $$\|u\|_{2,\Omega}^2\le C(\|F\|_{0,\Omega}+\|\phi\|_{1/2,\partial\Omega})$$
Is there any result available if we have condition $\gamma(x)\ge 0$?

Any hint or reference will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The equation you are dealing with in not exactly a elliptic equation, but it is an equation with non positive characteristics: perhaps the references cited in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/386913/existence-of-a-solution-for-this-hypoelliptic-alike-pde/387027#387027) may contain something useful for you.